# Cannot get TRUE when assigning report URL Param to a field

Tags: parameter-passing, looker-studio, looker

I have a param coming in from a URL.

It is seen on the report/dashboard side.

However when I try to assign this paramater to the field to use as a filter the resolution is always FALSE.

if

Filter_Field_In_DataSet = thepassed in parameter <-- this always returns FALSE - both feilds are of type TEXT

Everything have had no luck